# Material-UI TextField component error and helperText prop sees my state as undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, textfield

I am trying to do a validation with help of my state on TextField component, but what ever i want to pass from my state to error or helperText prop, it sees it as undefined, even though fo example console.log of state after in render can see that state. It can also see if i pass to error prop for example:

```
error={parcelNumberInput.errorText.length > 0}
```

I get an error which says that it can't read length propertie of "null"
So this is evidence that it can see that state?
So if i do it like you can see i did in code below, i get this error:

[image]

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";

const POST_CODE_MAX_LENGTH = 5;
const PARCEL_NUM_MAX_LENGTH = 14;

class CashReceiptForm extends Component {
  state = {
    parcel: { parcelNumber: "", postCode: "" },
    submitButton: { isDisabled: false, isLoading: false },
    inputValidation: {
      parcelNumberInput: { errorText: null, error: false },
      postCodeInput: { errorText: null, error: false }
    }
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    console.log("value", value);
    console.log("name", name);

    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      this.setState({
        parcel: {
          ...this.state.parcel,
          [name]: value
        }
      });
    } else {
      if (name === "parcelNumber") {
        this.setState({
          inputValidation: {
            parcelNumberInput: {
              errorText: "Musia byť čísla"
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          inputValidation: {
            postCodeInput: {
              errorText: "Musia byť čísla"
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("this.state", this.state);
  };

  render() {
    const { parcelNumber, postCode } = this.state.parcel;
    const { parcelNumberInput, postCodeInput } = this.state.inputValidation;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div className="page-header page-header-top-margin-none">
            <h2 className="page-title">
              Elektronický Príjmový Pokladničný Doklad
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div className="box box-small">
            <div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="form-control">
                  <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    helperText={parcelNumberInput.errorText}
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: PARCEL_NUM_MAX_LENGTH }}
                    error={parcelNumberInput.errorText !== null}
                    id="parcel-number"
                    label="Číslo zásielky"
                    name="parcelNumber"
                    type="text"
                    value={parcelNumber}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                  <TextField
                    helperText={postCodeInput.errorText}
                    inputProps={{ maxLength: POST_CODE_MAX_LENGTH }}
                    error={postCodeInput.errorText !== null}
                    id="post-code"
                    label="PSČ"
                    name="postCode"
                    type="text"
                    value={postCode}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                    margin="normal"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="button-group">
                <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CashReceiptForm.propTypes = {
  parcelNumber: PropTypes.number,
  postCode: PropTypes.number
};

export default CashReceiptForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're setting state with the new `inputValidation` error, you're completely overwriting the existing value of `this.state.inputValidation` (effectively removing them).

To keep the previous state values when updating `this.state.inputValidation`, you need to re-add them to the object, for example, by spreading them back into the object:

```
      if (name === "parcelNumber") {
        this.setState({
          inputValidation: {
            ...this.state.inputValidation, /** Here **/
            parcelNumberInput: {
              errorText: "Musia byť čísla"
            },
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          inputValidation: {
            ...this.state.inputValidation, /** And here **/
            postCodeInput: {
              errorText: "Musia byť čísla"
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ludpo?file=/CashReceiptForm.js